# Error in Pyspark : Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 69.0 failed 1 times ; ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: pyspark

I was attempting a simple rightOuterJoin, in Pyspark. The datasets which I am trying to join are the following

```
temp1.take(5)
```

Out[138]:

```
[u'tube_assembly_id,component_id_1,quantity_1,component_id_2,quantity_2,component_id_3,quantity_3,component_id_4,quantity_4,component_id_5,quantity_5,component_id_6,quantity_6,component_id_7,quantity_7,component_id_8,quantity_8',
 u'TA-00001,C-1622,2,C-1629,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA',
 u'TA-00002,C-1312,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA',
 u'TA-00003,C-1312,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA',
 u'TA-00004,C-1312,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA']

In [139]:

temp2.take(5)

Out[139]:
[u'tube_assembly_id,spec1,spec2,spec3,spec4,spec5,spec6,spec7,spec8,spec9,spec10',
 u'TA-00001,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA',
 u'TA-00002,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA',
 u'TA-00003,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA',
 u'TA-00004,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA']
```

The join command is as follows

In [140]:

```
temp4 = temp1.rightOuterJoin(temp2)
```

​
​

```
temp4
Out[140]:
PythonRDD[191] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43
```

However, When I attempt to do any of the operations like

`temp4.take(4)` or `temp4.count()` I get the long error as listed below

---

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-3372dfa2c550> in <module>()
----> 1 temp4.take(5)

/usr/local/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1222 
   1223             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1224             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p, True)
   1225 
   1226             items += res

/usr/local/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
    840         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
    841         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, javaPartitions,
--> 842                                           allowLocal)
    843         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
    844 

/usr/local/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 74.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 74.0 (TID 78, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 101, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 96, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 236, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/local/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1806, in <lambda>
    map_values_fn = lambda (k, v): (k, f(v))
ValueError: too many values to unpack

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:205)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Appreciate help on this. I am new to Pyspark

Comment: You might want to take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited it as per the desired format

Comment: Formatting looks way better now!

Comment: Do you have any solutions to the above problem ?? Please help if any

Comment: Sorry, I absolutely have no knowledge about pyspark.